# does this struct need a non-default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, struct

I have the following `struct` in C++, and I wondered if I need to define a non-default constructor for it when I use it as follows: `boost::shared_ptr<node> p_node = boost:shared_ptr<node>();`

```
struct node
{
    std::string name;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<variant> > values; // it is possible that nodes contain as a value, key/value pairs so we need a map

    NodeType type;  //Enum

    typedef struct attrib
    {
        std::string key;
        variant value;  //Boost::variant
    };

    std::vector<attrib> attributes;

    boost::shared_ptr<node> childnode;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"does this POD need a non-default constructor"... what POD?  POD's don't contain complex objects like strings and maps.  POD stands for plain old data, which is things like doubles and char arrays.

Whether you need a constructor depends on whether you want to make sure all the data is initialised in some sane state.  `std::map`, `std::vector` and `std::string` are all initialised for you to be empty.  The other `boost::shared_ptr` will be `NULL`.  `attrib` is only a type and you won't initially have any attrib objects, so no worries there.  But, your **NodeType enum isn't initialised** anywhere unless you do it yourself in a constructor.  Does that matter?  Only you can decide, but technically you MUST make sure you assign to it somewhere before reading from it, otherwise you technically get undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is [not a POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Modification_to_the_definition_of_plain_old_data).

Yes, this struct needs a default ctor, because otherwise the enum member will have an undefined value after default construction. It doesn't matter how you use it -- or, as in your example code `boost::shared_ptr<node> p_node = boost:shared_ptr<node>();` do not use it at all, as that just initializes a NULL shared ptr and you could just as well have written `boost::shared_ptr<node> p_node;`

Comment: The type member may *potentially* have an undefined value. The compiler generated default constructor can do both `zero-initialization` and `default initialization` depending on situation. A variable of static storage duration ([basic.start.init]) is zero initialized. A variable of automatic or dynamic storage duration declared with empty braces () is `value-initialized` which results in zero-initialization of members if there is no user defined constructor ([dcl.init] paragraph 8). `zero-initialization` does what it sounds like and sets POD values (like enums) to zero.

Comment: @M.Y.: Yeah, and given all this, it's probably a pretty good idea to add a default ctor that does proper initialization :-)

Answer (score 1):

1-) If you define any constructor (with 0 or 1 or n parameter) in your struct or class then C++ default constructor will not be created automatically.

So every thing is now depend only on your call to constructor.

if you create object Node* x = new Node(); This must call constructor with no parameter and your class must have constructor with no parameter[Read First Line Again].

Lets check if there is any constructor with no parameter in your struct or class. I say it again if you create any constructor with any number of parameter in C++ then default constructor will not be created by C++ interpreter automatically.

Line 1 is very important to understand.